# JavaFX image fit to the width of ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scrollpane

I'm trying to load an image inside a `ScrollPane` and make the image always fit to the width of the `ScrollPane`, even on window resize, so that you only have to scroll vertically. I'm using Scene Builder 8.5.0 and the Fit To Width property of the `ScrollPane` is set to true, but it doesn't work and the image still expands beyond the visible width of the `ScrollPane`. Preserve Ratio is also set to true. Here is the component hierarchy I used for this:

[image]

I also tried setting the fit to width property with code, but this doesn't work either

```
imgScrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You need to ensure that the image view's `fitWidth` property is set to the surrounding `AnchorPane`'s width. A quick-and-dirty way would simply be to bind it, but that's not really an optimal approach: better is to create a custom pane to hold the `ImageView` and update the `ImageView`'s `fitWidth` property in the `layoutChildren()` method.

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed your approach with the use of an `AnchorPane` does not work as you expected.

I agree with the comment from James_D and created two examples. The first example is the *„quick-and-dirty way“* with a simple `Binding` between the  `fitWidthProperty` of the `ImageView` and the `widthProperty` of the `ScrollPane`. The second example contains a little sample class customized for your needs which overrides the `layoutChildren()` method.

**Example 1** (quick-and-dirty with `Binding`):

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        
        String imageUrl = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/2e9/fisherman-in-the-lighthouse-1496152.jpg";
        Image image = new Image(imageUrl);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(imageView);
        
        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        // Example of how the Binding could be (here: take into account if the vertical scroll bar is showing or not):
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {

            // Find the vertical scroll bar of the scroll pane:
            Optional<ScrollBar> verticalScrollBarOpt = scrollPane.lookupAll(".scroll-bar").stream()
                    .filter(node -> node instanceof ScrollBar)
                    .map(node -> (ScrollBar) node)
                    .filter(scrollBar -> scrollBar.getOrientation() == Orientation.VERTICAL).findAny();

            if (verticalScrollBarOpt.isPresent() && verticalScrollBarOpt.get().isVisible())
                return scrollPane.getWidth() - verticalScrollBarOpt.get().getWidth();
            else
                return scrollPane.getWidth();

        }, scrollPane.widthProperty()));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 1300, 600));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Example 2** (custom class with `layoutChildren()`):

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        String imageUrl = "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/2e9/fisherman-in-the-lighthouse-1496152.jpg";
        Image image = new Image(imageUrl);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        CustomImagePane customImagePane = new CustomImagePane(imageView);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(customImagePane);

        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 1300, 600));
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * A simplified example how your custom control could look like.
     */
     public class CustomImagePane extends Region {

        private final ObjectProperty<ImageView> imageView = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public CustomImagePane(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                if (oldValue != null)
                    getChildren().remove(oldValue);

                if (newValue != null)
                    getChildren().add(newValue);
            });
            this.imageView.set(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            ImageView imageView = getImageView();
            if (imageView != null) {

                imageView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
                imageView.setFitHeight(0);

                layoutInArea(imageView, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
            }
            super.layoutChildren();
        }

        public ImageView getImageView() {
            return imageView.get();
        }

        public ObjectProperty<ImageView> imageViewProperty() {
            return imageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView.set(imageView);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```